# I can see a API response in browser but not with Ajax, why?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I have an api from the backend, if I visit the url in browser directly, I can see the response correctly, but if I load it with Ajax, I always get a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

The page and the api are in the same domain: `http://xx.com` and `http://xx.com/api`.

This is really weird, how could it happen?

Update: I explored it a little further and found that even `var img = new Image(); img.src = url;` get a 502 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this page](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html) helpfully explains, "the upstream server and the gateway/proxy do not agree on the protocol for exchanging data."  This could happen, in this case, because your Ajax request specifies different headers (such as a different "Accept" header), leading to a different entity type (i.e., body) being exchanged between your proxy and your actual back-end.  I would advise using a tool like Firebug or the Chrome debugger to examine the details of your regular request and your Ajax request, look for significant differences, and add headers to your Ajax request as needed to get the desired result.